# the generators of $I$ when $\mathbb C[x,y]/I$ is Gorenstein with zero dimension 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be any ideal in $R=\mathbb C[x,y]$ of height 2. If we know the localization of $I$ at any maximal ideal $m\supseteq I$ is generated by a regular sequence of length two in $R_m$. Is this true that $I$ itself is generated by a regular sequence of length two in $R$?

Comment: It's pretty late here, so I hope this isn't completely nonsensical. A Gorenstein ring is Cohen-Macaulay and both $R_m$ and $R$ are local Gorenstein and so local Cohen-Macaulay. For such rings any ideal $I$  has height equal to the depth of $I$ with respect to $I$. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_(ring_theory). Also, all regular sequences in $I$ have length equal to the depth of $I$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_(algebra). Now, $R$ is already local, so it seems height = depth = length of longest regular sequence even without this bit about $R_m$. How does that sound?

Comment: What do you mean by '$R$ is already local'?

Comment: Could you give the reference for the claim: If $R$ is local then $I$ generated by a regular sequence? 

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way to see this is the following. If $I_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is generated by a regular sequence, using Koszul complex, one gets that $Ext^1(I,R)$ is locally isomorphic to $R/I$ and thus by Chinese remainder theorem, globally isomorphic to $R/I$. Then one checks that the extension corresponding to $1\in Ext^1(I,R)$, say $0\to R\to P\to I\to 0$ has $P$ a projective $R$-module of rank 2 and by Seshadri's theorem $P$ is free. Thus $I$ is 2-generated. Easy to arrange the generators to be a regular sequnce.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you explain in details why the identity $1\in Ext^1(I,R)$ corresponds to a ses $0\rightarrow R\rightarrow P\rightarrow I\to 0$ where $P$ is projective? 

Comment: Let me describe one of may ways of seeing this. By the very nature of it, $P$ is torsion free and hence has depth at least one. That it comes from a generator of $Ext^1(I,R)$ also implies $Ext^1(P,R)=0$. If  $P$ is not projective, by Auslander-Buchsbaum formula, $pd P$ must be one. Writing a resolution $0\to A\to B\to P\to 0$ with $A,B$ free, using the fact that $Ext^1(P,R)=0$, one easily checks that $P$ must be projective.

Answer (score 0):

Hi. I'm a little bit confused by the above example. The way I looked at this is through Forster-Swan number.

[Forster] Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $M$ a finite $R$-module. Then $M$ can be generated by $b(M)$ elements.

Here $b(M) = 0$ if $M = 0$ and 
$b(M) =$ sup { $\mu(M_p) + $ dim $R/p$ } where $p \in $ supp$(M)$ if $M \neq 0$.

If we take $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $M = I$ as in the question. Then $b(M) = 2$. So $I$ can be generated by two elements.

Comment: In this case $b(M)=3$, since $0\in Supp(M)$ where $M=I$. In fact, Forster-Swan does not use the fact you are working over a polynomial ring and in general, you will not be able to do better than 3 for arbitrary rings of dimension 2.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It is 3 not 2. Thank you for the clarification. 